# HAProxy shows Connect() failed for backend: no free ports, but there are plenty ephemeral ports free

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

I use haproxy 2.0.18 on Ubuntu 18.0.4. We are load balancing various connections (mainly tcp, some http) to four backend servers.

One of the ports regularly shows the following error message, which indicates that there are no more ephemeral ports left:

```
Connect() failed for backend int-tlsports-20515: no free ports.
```

However, in total only around 4000 connections exist and the ephemeral ports are plenty:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
1024    60999
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2.5 and got this today after adding `default-server resolvers dns init-addr last,libc,none` (just the resolvers dns part is new). When removing `resolvers dns`, the free port error is away. Seems to be a bug, because there are enough local ports available. I can download from the same host. And the free ports is only reported for the first backend with a server.

Comment: Ah... for me I found the problem... haproxy resolves an ipv6 address, but the environment does not route ipv6. After adding `resolve-prefer ipv4` to the default-server in the comment above, it works as expected. So maybe the error wants to tell us that there is no ipv6 socket possible?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, I have configured the backend servers using ipv4 addresses. Maybe I try to upgrade haproxy to 2.2

Answer (score 3):

As per comment from @markus, `resolve-prefer ipv4` seems to have resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have this directive in configuration file

```
backend https_example
   server srv.example.com srv.example.com:443
```

So haproxy host redirect the connection to itself and run out of free ports.